# Point position doesn't change even if the data in glBufferData change

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

code:

```py
import glfw
import numpy as np
from OpenGL.GL import *

def main():
    if not glfw.init():
        raise RuntimeError('Can not initialize glfw library')
    window = glfw.create_window(500, 500, 'Demo', None, None)
    if not window:
        glfw.terminate()
        raise RuntimeError('Can not create glfw window')
    glfw.make_context_current(window)

    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1)
    glColor(1, 0, 0, 1)
    glPointSize(10.0)

    VBO = glGenBuffers(1)
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO)

    # The result of following two lines are looks the same
    # glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, np.array([0, 0, 0], dtype='float32'), GL_STATIC_DRAW)
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, np.array([999999999, 999999999, 999999999], dtype='float32'), GL_STATIC_DRAW)

    while not glfw.window_should_close(window):
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO)
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0)
        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 1)
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0)

        glfw.swap_buffers(window)
        glfw.poll_events()

    glfw.terminate()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I'm studying OpenGL and I'm trying to follow the tutorial [here](https://ogldev.org/www/tutorial02/tutorial02.html). However, I found the position of the point never change even if I change the data in "glBufferData".

I don't known how this happened.  Is the function glBufferData not working? Or maybe I made some low-level mistakes.

Comment: Where's your vertex shader code?

Comment: I'm just follow a tutorial and I don't known what is vertex shader code. Do I need that? Can this program run without vertex shader code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a named buffer object is bound, then the 6th parameter of `glVertexAttribPointer` is treated as a byte offset into the buffer object's data store. However the type of the parameter is `c_void_p`.

Therfore if the offset is 0, then the 6th parameter can either be `None` or `c_void_p(0)` else the offset has to be caste to `c_void_p(0)`:

<s>`glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0)`</s>

```py
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, None)
```

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import glfw
import numpy as np
from OpenGL.GL import *

def main():
    if not glfw.init():
        raise RuntimeError('Can not initialize glfw library')
    window = glfw.create_window(500, 500, 'Demo', None, None)
    if not window:
        glfw.terminate()
        raise RuntimeError('Can not create glfw window')
    glfw.make_context_current(window)

    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1)
    glColor(1, 0, 0, 1)
    glPointSize(10.0)

    VBO = glGenBuffers(1)
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO)
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, np.array([0.2, -0.2, 0, -0.2, -0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 0], dtype='float32'), GL_STATIC_DRAW)

    while not glfw.window_should_close(window):
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO)
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, None)
        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 3)
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0)

        glfw.swap_buffers(window)
        glfw.poll_events()

    glfw.terminate()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm still confuse why 0 offset is different from c_void_p(0). What if I need set the offset to 2? Do I pass c_void_p(2) to the 6-th parameter?

Comment: @Finn Yes `c_void_p(2)`. Don't bother you. The underlying c type is `void*`. PyOpenGL requires here a _pointer_ and _int_ doesn't work for whatever reason. (See [`glVertexAttribPointer`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glVertexAttribPointer.html)).